# Play route syntax for ignoring a part of slug

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

What we want is basically this:

```
/foo/*                 controllers.FooController.foo
```

However this doesn't work.

We have found the following workaround:

```
/foo/*ignore           controllers.FooController.foo(ignore)
```

But this makes the code of the method `controllers.FooController.foo` slightly ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's ugly with that?

Comment: @i.am.michiel, the definition for `foo` will look like: `def foo(ignored: String = "") = Action { ... }`. The test code now looks like `foo()(fakeRequest)`. I would like a less intrusive way of handling a "ignore" part in slug.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code over [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/routes-compiler/src/main/scala/play/router/RoutesCompiler.scala#L156), the router isn't able to deal with the "slug" part without specifying an `identifier`... the parser combinator doesn't declare it as optional, and the `map` (`^^`) is clearly using it as is.

It could be a good feature request if it wouldn't induce other problems where a pattern will hide all other routes because it's defined higher in the file (or even worst, included).

And it looks like it has been done on purpose if we look [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/routes-compiler/src/main/scala/play/router/RoutesCompiler.scala#L345), we can figure out that dynamic parameter cannot be assigned a default value -- indeed, in this case we'll fall in the case I've just mentioned :-/.

My first advice would be to tell you to use `ignore` as an `Option[String]` and the action definition to set it as `None` (rather than an empty `String` because it's more expressive).
My second would be to incite you to wonder if such case is really relevant, because it's error prone and could hide further problems